# Given a random bit string with length 15. Let event A be an even number of 1's and B be no consecutive 1's?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

How do I find the probability of this? I'm completely lost...

I just need P(A) and P(B)

Comment: So do you want $P(A\cap B)$?  Or $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ separately?  Or something else?  Please clarify the question.

Comment: $P(A)=\frac12$ and $P(B)=\frac{1597}{32768}$.

Comment: @bof how did you get 1597?

Comment: I used the recurrence relation; see David's answer, or look up "Fibonacci numbers".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**.  There are $2^{15}$ bit strings of length $15$, so you need to count the number of "favourable" bit strings in each case and divide by $2^{15}$.  To start off $A$, find how many bit strings have two $1$s.

(1) choose $2$ of the $15$ places to be $1$s. . . . . this can be done in ??? ways
(2) put $0$s in the remaining places. . . . . this can be done in only one way.

Then do the same for all even numbers up to $15$.

**Short cut**.  What can you say if you compare the number of bit strings with an even number of $1$s and the number of bit strings with an even number of $0$s?

For $B$ you probably need to use a recurrence relation.  Let $b_n$ be the number of $n$-digit bit strings with no consecutive $1$s.  See if you can explain why
$$b_n=b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}$$
for all $n\ge3$, and use this to calculate $b_{15}$.